# Can I set lower heap size for CouchDB in order to prevent "Can not allocate memory" errors?

Tags: erlang, out-of-memory, couchdb

CouchDB (commit: [b029b67](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/tree/b029b6789d04606eb2145f12fbd0867553aead5c)) dies because of "insufficient" memory when I require any of relatively large views:

```
[info] 2017-01-03T16:28:35.523858Z couchdb@localhost <0.756.0> -------- Starting index update for db: shards/00000000-1fffffff/mydb.1483425014 idx: _design/orders
[info] 2017-01-03T16:28:35.523989Z couchdb@localhost <0.754.0> -------- Starting index update for db: shards/80000000-9fffffff/mydb.1483425014 idx: _design/orders
[info] 2017-01-03T16:28:35.524235Z couchdb@localhost <0.755.0> -------- Starting index update for db: shards/c0000000-dfffffff/mydb.1483425014 idx: _design/orders
[info] 2017-01-03T16:28:35.944351Z couchdb@localhost <0.741.0> -------- Opening index for db: shards/e0000000-ffffffff/mydb.1483425014 idx: _design/orders sig: "25d074b71c60188a31fca87891ee036c"
[info] 2017-01-03T16:28:35.944894Z couchdb@localhost <0.780.0> -------- Starting index update for db: shards/e0000000-ffffffff/mydb.1483425014 idx: _design/orders
[os_mon] memory supervisor port (memsup): Erlang has closed
[os_mon] cpu supervisor port (cpu_sup): Erlang has closed

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
eheap_alloc: Cannot allocate 127744576 bytes of memory (of type "heap", thread 2).
Aborted
```

Here is my RAM status while CouchDB is down:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       4148228    1048880    3099348      18412      10048     834928
-/+ buffers/cache:     203904    3944324
Swap:      7812092      12944    7799148
```

Here is the `./etc/local.ini` (I found relevant):

```
[couchdb]
os_process_timeout = 240000

[query_server_config]
os_process_limit = 130000
```

Is it normal for CouchDB to require such amount of RAM or is there something misconfigured that I can change?